# Crystal Reports Multiple IIF LEFT functions

Tags: if-statement, syntax, crystal-reports

I'm trying to replace two values in a column, I was reading through the Crystal syntax docs and saw that I should be able to use ; to separate functions but run two, however when I use it likes this:

```
IIF(LEFT({v_FrameDepartment.cftliner}, 4) = "FT-T", "Tulip", 
    {v_FrameDepartment.cftliner});
IIF(LEFT({v_FrameDepartment.cftliner}, 4) = "FT-V", "Veneer", 
    {v_FrameDepartment.cftliner})
```

It only runs the second result. Is there a way to run both of these on the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only returning the result of the second because a single formula may only have a single return value. In your case, you have two separate statements so the first value is "lost" in a sense as it's never assigned to a variable. Instead, try something like:

```
//You can separate the two statements with a ';' since we're assigning to a variable
local stringvar cftVar := left({v_FrameDepartment.cftliner}, 4);
select cftVar
case "FT-T" : "Tulip"
case "FT-V" : "Veneer"
default : {v_FrameDepartment.cftliner}
```